# How to switch between roles from the ec2 cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I provision an ec2 instance with a specific role. I want to the change the assumed role later form the ec2 cli to gain crross-account access, do something, and then switch back to my original role. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the ~/.aws/config file with the additional profile added.

- Assuming that RoleA is your Instance Profile Role,
- RoleB is the RoleB is the role you want to assume
- RoleA has sts:assumerole

Update your ~/.aws/config to look like the following

```
[profile roleb]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123412341234:role/RoleB
region=us-east-1
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

So when you want to run the role from the assumed role b you would

```
aws s3 --profile roleb ls
```

For more info
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

Answer (score 1):

You would not *switch* to another role. Rather, you would request temporary credentials associated with another role, then use those new credentials to make API calls.

The steps would be:

- Call `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::nnn:role/your-role --role-session-name foo`
- Grab the temporary credentials that are returned. I would recommend storing them in the `~/.aws/credentials` file by using `aws configure --profile role2`
- Then make API call with that role, such as: `aws s3 ls --profile role2`

To use the original credentials, just leave off the `--profile`.

Comment: @zED is quite right -- the AWS CLI can actually do all the above for you because it now accepts a Role as a profile. See: [Assuming an IAM Role in the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)